# gobject.MainLoop and tornado.IOLoop at once?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, pygtk, tornado

How can you run two event loops in one application?

I need to use [tornado.IOLoop](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#ioloop-objects) (WebSocket client) and [gobject.MainLoop](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gobjectmainloop.html) (pygtk) in one Python program.

**Update:** Threadless solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my [gioloop.py](https://gist.github.com/schlamar/8420193). This is a IOLoop implementation with `gobject.io_add_watch`, so it's a single-threaded solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a thread

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=my_ioloop.start).start()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. A solution without threads would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of messy, but you can run Tornado on top of the gobject event loop all in one thread with Twisted.  Follow the "Tornado on Twisted" directions at http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/twisted.html#tornado-on-twisted and use Twisted's gireactor (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.gireactor.html).

It would also be possible to write an IOLoop implementation that uses gobject directly without going through Twisted, but as far as I know no one's done that yet.

Comment: BTW, Twisted's GTK reactor is **not** single-threaded on Windows.